# Перевести цифровые символы из строки char в динамический массив int

Tags: c, char

Суть задания в том, что существует некий ряд символов из которого нам нужно изъять цифровые символы, из этих самых цифровых символов создать новый ряд и превратить их в числа.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{ 
int i=0;
char c;
int numbers;
char *charac;
int *numeric;
charac = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
numeric = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
if(charac == NULL) 
{
    printf("Вы ничего не ввели!");
    exit(1);
}
printf("Введите символы(закончив нажми Enter): ");
while((c = getchar()) != '\n') 
{
    charac[i++] = c;
}
printf("\nСимвольный ряд: %s", charac);

    if(charac[i] >= '0' && charac[i] <= '9')
    {
        numeric[numbers] = charac[i];
        sscanf(charac[i] , "%d", &numbers); 
        numbers++;
    }
printf("\nЦифровой ряд: %s\n", numeric);
}
```

Comment: А проблема в том, что "Цифровой  ряд:" не выводится...

Comment: `int numbers = 0;`, наверное. Не говоря уже о том бреде, который идёт после этой строки до самого конца файла.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{ 
    int i=0;
    int numbers=0;
    char charac[255];
    char numeric[255];

    printf("Введите символы(закончив нажми Enter): ");
    scanf("%s", charac);
    if(strlen(charac) == 0) 
    {
        printf("Вы ничего не ввели!");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("\nСимвольный ряд: %s\n", charac);

    for(i=0; i<strlen(charac); i++)
    {
        if(charac[i] >= '0' && charac[i] <= '9')
        {
        numeric[numbers++] = charac[i];
        }
    }
    numeric[numbers] = '\0';

    printf("\nЦифровой ряд: %s\n", numeric);
}
```

Comment: Что будет, когда вводить будем 256 символов?

Comment: Во первых, не думаю, что препод, принимающий зачёт у первокурсника, задаст такой вопрос. А во вторых,  чудес не бывает, а потому, при выполнении **любой** операции ввода нужно выделить буфер **достаточного** размера. Что значит **достаточного** - решать автору программы.